# Jenkins Git Plugin Fails to StoreAddition Behaviors in job xml?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We see problems with GitPlugin in jenkins.  Plugin appears to not write any  additional behaviors to job xml and therefore loses those settings upon clone or restart.

Anyone else seeing this?

Here's my Test:

- Configure simple jenkins job with **Source Code Management** for git with a branch specifier
- Save and copy jobs config.xml to lacks-additional-behaviors.xml
- Configure same job and add in checkout-to-local-branch, clean-before-checkout, advanced-submodule-behaviours
- Save and copy jobs config.xml to has-additional-behaviors.xml
- Diff the two   **NO DIFFERENCES**

Jenkins: 1.627 
git Plugin: 1.19.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.19.6 sounds like the current version of `Git client plugin`, not `Git plugin` (the latter depends on the former). The issue you're describing matches [this bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33695) in the Git plugin, which was introduced in 2.4.3 and fixed in 2.4.4. So I'm guessing you're on Git plugin version 2.4.3.

My team was experiencing this same problem (our "Additional behaviours" were disappearing following a reboot). I just upgraded our Git plugin from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4 and the problem appears to be resolved. Now when I add behaviors to a job they are flushed to the config.xml file.

Comment: Sounds like it.  We worked around by switching our git jobs over to use jenkins-jobs-builder.  Once there, we only update the jobs via yaml and then push.  As long as we don't use the UI to modify, we are fine.   When we jump to jenkis 2.0 later in the month, we'll update all the plugins then.